# Implementing Friend Functions

Tags: c++, friend-function

I have two classes `Humidity` and `Temperature`. And they have friend function, that's declared in their header files:

```
friend
void PrintWeather(const Temperature &cTemperature, const Humidity &cHumidity);
```

Where is it convenient to implement the function (`Temperature.cpp`, `Humidity.cpp`, or `another_file.cpp`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the functions `PrintWeather` is not logically coupled
 to one class more than to the other, I would implement it in a separate file, maybe `weather.cpp`. I use lower case to show that the file doesn't contain the class `Weather`, but rather weather-related functions.

Also my strong suggestion is to use a namespace like `weather` for all these.

Without knowing more that you showed, I would question your design. Why does `PrintWeather` need to access the internals of `Temperature` and `Humidity`? It should just use the public interfaces of those two.

Comment: This is just an example from tutorial on friend functions. I've been interested what approaches are used in this kind of situations.

Comment: Or name the file something like `output_functions.cpp`. Or even better, create a `WeatherForecast` class containing a `Temperature` and `Humidity` object as fields, which has a `Print` function.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the `PrintWeather` function implies that it talks about something called the `Weather`. So maybe you should make `Weather` (or `WeatherForecast`) into a separate class, which collects all the components of the weather:

```
class Weather
{
  private: 
    Temperature temperature;
    Humidity humidity;

  public:
    void Print();
    // or: void Print(std::ostream& out) const;
}
```

Note how the name of the function can now simply be `Print` - *what* it prints is already clear from the class it lives in and instead of the awkward

```
weatherForecast.PrintWeather();
```

you get to write

```
weatherForecast.Print();
```

Now you can grant `Weather` `friend` access to `Temperature` and `Humidity`,  if your assignment requires you to do so. However, I'd like to point out that in actual design you want to avoid `friend`s as much as possible (as the saying goes: *"you don't want your friends to touch your privates"* - just provide `Temperature` and `Humidity` with the appropriate `public` interface).